# Specifying sessionToken lifetime when calling AWS Cognito GetCredentialsForIdentity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

for debugging purposes I would really like to know how I can specify the lifetime of my cognito session token. The credentials have a default lifetime of 1 hour from what I can tell. I would like to lower that to testable 1 min for instance. Does anyone know?

I haven't found anything for this call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no. But if you use the legacy flow(three steps), you can call [AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity.html) and set DurationSeconds to minimum 15 mins.